# Globally set custom Bootstrap 4 button color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set the color of Bootstrap 4 buttons. Precisely I want to change the color of `btn-primary` while holding a mouse click down on it. It has to be some button event I have to colorize, but it does not appear to be in `hover`, `focus`, or `active`.

In my tests I got the button with the class `btn-primary` entirely red except while clicking on it, which turns the button blue. For creating CSS I make use of Sass.

My app.scss file:

```
.btn-primary {
    &:hover {
        color: red;
        background-color: red;
    }
    &:focus {
        color: red;
        background-color: red;
    }
    &:active {
        color: red;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

How can I set the color of the button while clicking on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use with !important.

```css
.btn-primary:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.btn-primary:focus {
  color: red;
  background-color: orange !important;
}

.btn-primary:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Or, without using !important:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
.btn-primary:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.btn-primary:focus {
  color: red;
  background-color: orange;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Ok, `.btn-primary:hover { background-color: red !important;` solved the case. In my experience `!important` should be avoided though. Is there a way around it in this case?